ABP VNext taticHttpClientProxies
I want to use a static proxy call method in the "program" method of the console, but an exception occurred. Tracing the source code, I found that
The 'IAbpLazyService Provider' in 'Client Proxy Base' is null
Is it because they are not in the same context? How should I solve it?
}
public class Program
{
    public async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var application = AbpApplicationFactory.Create<MyConsoleAppModule>())
        {
            application.Initialize();

            var helloWorldService =
                   application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWarningConfigAppService>();
            if (helloWorldService != null)
            {
                var t = await helloWorldService.GetListAsync(new Q_WarningConfigDto());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop application...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


I have already resolved it
public class Program
    {
        public async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var application = AbpApplicationFactory.Create<HniotSWCMSConsoleModule>(options =>
            {
                options.Services.AddAutofacServiceProviderFactory();
            }))
            {
              
                application.Initialize();
    
                var currentTenant = application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentTenant>();
                using (currentTenant.Change(Guid.Parse("3A05A2F9-6BF9-1165-0FDE-1981307AEF8C")))
                {
          
                    var warningConfigAppService = application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWarningConfigAppService>();
    
                    if (warningConfigAppService != null)
                    {
                        var result = await warningConfigAppService.GetListAsync(new Q_WarningConfigDto());
                        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(result)}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to resolve IWarningConfigAppService.");
                    }
                }
    
                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop application...");
                Console.ReadLine();
    
                application.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

